# Find the joint probability density of the two random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

Find the joint probability density of the two random variables X and Y whose joint
distribution function is given by

$F(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
(1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y}),  & x>0 \text{ and } y>0 \\[2ex]
0, & \text{elshewhere (where is this exacty?)}
\end{cases}$

Use joint probability density to determine $P(1<X<3,1<Y<2)$.

In order to solve we use JDF Theorem

$F(x,y) = P(X\le x,Y \le y)= \int^{y}_{-\infty} \int^{x}_{-\infty} f(s,t) \text{ds dt}$

Yet what alludes me is how ones derives the correct answer from this.

Does one have to take the gradient of this to arrive at the right result?
Of This problem?

$(1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y}) = 1-e^{-y}-e^{-x}+e^{-xy}$ ?

Comment: "Elsewhere" is $x \le 0$ or $y \le 0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of the green region in the plot below is what you want. You could use
the joint CDF (your last equation, subject to limits) several times to get that probability.

Maybe, start by finding
$P(X \le 3, X \le 2).$ Piece it together by subtracting two probabilities
from that and then adding back another.

The plot is based on a simulation of a million points in R statistical software. This allows one
to find the *approximate* probability in the green rectangle.

```
x = rexp(10^6);  y = rexp(10^6)
cond.x = (x > 1 & x < 3)
cond.y = (y > 1 & y < 2)
cond = cond.x & cond.y
mean(cond)
## 0.073555  # aprx answer
plot(x,y, pch=".", col="skyblue")
points(x[cond],y[cond], pch=".", col="darkgreen")
abline(v = c(1,3), col="red");  abline(h = c(1,2), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what the objective is: to find the joint PDF or to evaluate the probability. $X$ and $Y$ are iid $Exp(rate=1),$ so the joint PDF is $f(x,y) = e^{-x}\cdot e^{-y} = e^{-(x+y)},$ for $x, y > 0.$ Also, $P(1 < X < 3) = 0.3180924,\, P(1 < Y < 2) = 0.2325442,$ and by indep $P(1 < X < 3, 1 < Y < 2) = 0.07397052.$ I dealt with the joint CDF as you asked, but I'm not quite sure why it is part of the Problem.